# Identifying A Series: Geometric Affine-Functional

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to identify if this type of sum has been studied.

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an affine function,

$$f(x) = a + bx.$$

The series in question is

$$S(n) = x + f(x) + f(f(x)) + f(f(f(x))) + \cdots + f^{n-1}(x).$$

I'm also interested in

$$\tilde{S}(n) = \exp(x) + \exp(f(x)) + \exp(f(f(x))) + \cdots + \exp(f^{n-1}(x))$$

Comment: Just clarifying... $f^{n-1}(x)$ means the composition of $f(x)$ with itself $n-2$ times, right? I’m saying this because $f^{n-1}(x)$ is used to symbolize the $n-1$-th derivative of $f(x)$, and that doesn’t make sense with what you said before.

Comment: @MathAndPhysics yes, sorry for abuse of notations, but I could not think of a better way to write it than to show it in the previous terms.